# How to close any system dialog during execution instrumentation tests

Tags: android, testing, ui-testing, android-uiautomator, android-espresso

I have a farm of about 20 android devices to run instrumentation UI tests. I use Espresso. Sometimes different system dialogs appear and lead tests to fail.
E.g. USSD result dialog, dialog of lost internet connection, dialog of request to update OS and etc.

Is there a way to catch **any** dialog and close the one?
This intent doesn't help.

```
Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I did not find the only solution and I decided to process every dialogs failed the tests.

Answer (score 1):

it’s simple to click back button event

**onView(isRoot()).perform(ViewActions.pressBack());**

Add this to your gradle:

**androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'**

And then do this in your test:

**UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
mDevice.pressBack();**

and if you like more in Espresso UI testing, View Expresso Demo Project on GitHub: https://github.com/ranaNarin/Espresso-Android 
In this demo project, implemented espresso in all Scenarios:- EditText, Button, options menu click, navigation drawer Open and close, click on recycler view item, open camera and click image using Espresso UI Testing

Comment: Thanks. Press back is easy and good solution, but there are dialogs that can not be closed by pressing back.

Comment: Please read [How not to be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). You must disclose your affiliation to any off-site links or you risk  being flagged for spam.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this.  The popups have an id and can be dismissed using the test framework. So far I've found how to do it using appium and there is another GitHub that has to this using instrumentation but I haven't implemented this yet.

https://github.com/jamesknowsbest/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android